# With Python ruamel.yaml, lost anchor when loading in round-trip mode?

Tags: python, ruamel.yaml

When loading a file containing anchors at different nesting levels, the anchor seems lost and the key remains empty.

When loading the following file:

```
---
Dict1:
    - InnerDict: &inner
            key: val

Dict2:
    InnerDict:
        <<: *inner

Dict3:
    - InnerDict:
        <<: *inner
...
```

... with the code (Python 3.7, ruamel.yaml version 0.15.78):

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
with open("file.yaml") as infile:
    content = YAML(typ='rt', pure=True).load(infile)
print(content)
```

... gives:

```
{'Dict1': [ordereddict([('InnerDict', ordereddict([('key', 'val')]))])],
 'Dict2': ordereddict([('InnerDict', ordereddict())]),
 'Dict3': [ordereddict([('InnerDict', ordereddict([('key', 'val')]))])]}
```

... where the inner dict of `Dict2` remains empty.

In safe mode, the anchor is interpreted as expected in both cases.

Is it intended or is it a bug ?

Answer (score 1):

That is definitely a bug, and it has to do with the breadth-first
construction of mappings in the data structure. By the time the
`InnerDict` under `Dict2` is constructed, the one nested under `Dict1`
is not completely available. The `InnerDict` under `Dict3` lies at the
same depth, and can therefore correctly be constructed (and so can the
first merge if you remove the dash in the `Dict1` construction and so
making the anchor appear at a shallower place).

One way to solve this, apart from installing `ruamel.yaml>=0.15.79`, is by
providing an alternative constructor, that forces depth first processing:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

class MyConstructor(ruamel.yaml.constructor.RoundTripConstructor):
    def construct_yaml_map(self, node):
        data = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap()
        data._yaml_set_line_col(node.start_mark.line, node.start_mark.column)
        yield data
        self.construct_mapping(node, data, deep=True)
        self.set_collection_style(data, node)

MyConstructor.add_constructor(
    u'tag:yaml.org,2002:map', MyConstructor.construct_yaml_map
)


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.Constructor = MyConstructor


yaml_str = """\
Dict1:
    - InnerDict: &inner
            key: val

Dict2:
    InnerDict:
        <<: *inner

Dict3:
    - InnerDict:
        <<: *inner
"""

data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
for k in data:
   print(k, data[k])
print('---------')
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

Generating:

```
Dict1 [ordereddict([('InnerDict', ordereddict([('key', 'val')]))])]
Dict2 ordereddict([('InnerDict', ordereddict([('key', 'val')]))])
Dict3 [ordereddict([('InnerDict', ordereddict([('key', 'val')]))])]
---------
Dict1:
- InnerDict: &inner
    key: val

Dict2:
  InnerDict:
    <<: *inner

Dict3:
- InnerDict:
    <<: *inner
```

(As the dump of `data` is correct even without the above "patch", this
was not previously detected when testing round-trips)